# How to Logout Session Symfony Fos:Userbundle

Tags: php, symfony, backend, fosuserbundle

I am new to Symfony2, i am using FOSUserBundle. I overwrote the default template for the FOSUserBundle, and doing so i have lost the 'loggout' link on the profile page at

```
             resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
```

Is there a way to loggout from the symfony tool bar at the bottom?

and what is the resource link to loggout a user in fosUserBundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, that the default route for logout in FOSUerBundle is `"fos_user_security_logout"`, so you can generate a logout link anywhere in your site with this route:

```
<a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}">
```

It is also possible to add a new block to the Symfony2 debug toolbar with the logout link.
You should have a look here: [Adding Web Profiler Templates](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/profiler/data_collector.html#adding-web-profiler-templates)

You can extend the `'WebProfilerBundle:Profiler:layout.html.twig'` layout and add the custom content to the toolbar block.

```
{% block toolbar %}
    {# the web debug toolbar content #}
{% endblock %}
```